# Why two foreign keys in my model cause Foreign Key Constraint?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, data-annotations, ef-core-2.2

What's the workaround with this? Can this be achievable using data annotations?

```
public class QuestionModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public long AskedUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AskedUserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser AskedApplicationUser { get; set; }
    public long AskerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AskerId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser AskerApplicationUser { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string content { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnswered { get; set; }
}
```

What's the problem in this model? Why do I get this error :

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Questiions_AspNetUsers_AskerId' on table 'Questiions' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: I've read the command output and my thought is should I not use foreign keys?

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Questiions] PRIMARY KEY ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Questiions_AspNetUsers_AskedUserId] FOREIGN KEY ([AskedUserId]) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Questiions_AspNetUsers_AskerId] FOREIGN KEY ([AskerId]) REFERENCES [AspNetUsers] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

Answer (score 0):

You've got your `ForeignKey` decorations below the properties, when they should be above them. The attributes are being applied to the wrong properties.

You've also got multiple occurrences of the `AskedApplicationUser` property.

Try this:

```
public class QuestionModel
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AskedUserId")]
    public long AskedUserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AskerId")]
    public long AskerId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser AskedApplicationUser { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string content { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnswered { get; set; }
}
```